# Dark Souls 2 keeps crashing on load

Tags: technical-issues, dark-souls-2

So recently (today) my Dark Souls 2 game instantly crashing at the end of the loading screen. I thought maybe it was because I was using a symlink to sync my game saves as of a few days ago but I copied my saves folder back to where it was and it's still not working. Does anyone know what could cause this or maybe a good place to ask the question.

I'm running Windows 7 (64 bit) with an AMD Phenom II processor and AMD Radeon 6800 for my graphics card. Don't know if anything else would be relevant in terms of my computer environment.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is technical requirements (ram, sys req/graphical req) can u shard your current PC specs?

Comment: Well, I'm sure that I meet the technical requirements since it was working just fine until today. I have 8GB of RAM, don't know how much GRAM I have though.