# Dark Souls 2 Shutting Off Laptop on Low

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

Okay so this is a VERY strange issue. But I have a (very old, beaten, soon to be replaced) laptop with an AMD Radeon, 4GBs of RAM, and a 512 GB HDD. I tried running Dark Souls 2, and it SHUTS OFF my laptop after a few minutes. When I named my character, lighting the first bonfire, and stepping into the mist, all shut my laptop down and I was not able to turn it back on for an hour later each time. Strange thing is, this happens on any graphics setting on Dark Souls 2, but I can run games like Call Of Duty: Black Ops, Battlefield 3, BioShock Infinite, and League Of Legends fine, on high, no problems. What could possibly be going on? My laptop isn't even hot when this happens.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172635/dark-souls-2-keeps-crashing-on-load)... but it doesn't explain the power issue...

Comment: I just got done fixing a PSU problem (by replacing a 10 year old PSU) on a desktop system. One of the symptoms was that DS2 would shut down the computer when passing a mist wall. The game would work fine otherwise. I could reproduce it at will at certain specific mist walls.

Comment: @Yorik So replacing the PSU might work? But it might not be worth it since I'm getting a new laptop (AMD Lenovo) soon.

Comment: When XP came out, Microsoft made the PR move to "eliminate Blue Screens" (it was a selling point!) by setting the default to "automatically restart on Blue screen errors". Make sure you computer is set to *not* auto restart. If it still powers down, then you most likely have a power problem.

Comment: I think you ought to dig around and ensure it is not a software problem to save yourself some money chasing after shadows. Modern desktops ought not just power off for no reason, but laptops **do** have PSU/battery drivers that can complicate the picture. I was able to diagnose it finally by hooking up a second PSU to power my GPU PCIe card.

Comment: You say your laptop isn't hot, but did you verify that with a program like SpeedFan? This sounds like overheating.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [GEM/GeDoSaTo](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls2/mods/7/?) and scale down the graphics a bit to see if this will get things stable. Could also be that a specific component gets hot to localized for you to 'feel that it gets hot'. Give [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor-pro.html) a try.